# jquery ajax unexpected token :

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get a JSON file via:

```
$.ajax('/file.json', {
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, text, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR + " " + text + " " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

However, I always get this error:

```
parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

My JSON file it's very simple:

```
{
    stuff: "some stuff"
}
```

I've tried everything, I heard about some cross-domain thing but the JSON file is in the same directory of the html. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: can you get the json response of '/file.json' and post it too?

Comment: There might be a parse error in the json file. Post it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `stuff:` to `"stuff":` this is correct json Syntax.

Comment: Yeah It work!! Tanks. I feel pretty dummy right now

Comment: Nice. Bad json validator you used :). Try something like jshint. This realy helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing it to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'file.json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, text, errorThrown) {
      console.log(jqXHR + " " + text + " " + errorThrown);
  }
});
```

But it looks maybe some bad JSON is being returned. Try a different JSON file which you are certain is valid?

Also if the file.json is in same directly, ditch including the '/' before file.json. Unless you're running it from a virtual host or the web servers root

Comment: I checked, and my json file is valid

Comment: Updated my answer with a few changes try implementing them?

Comment: Yes, i tried bu i get: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token p"

Comment: @ReneLeyva I'm gonna wager a guess the error isn't in the AJAX call then, but either a) elsewhere in your code or b) in your JSON file. As others are requesting, we need to see the JSON to give accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
 dataType: 'jsonp'
```

to

```
 dataType: 'json'
```

Comment: If i change it i get: "unexpected token p"

Comment: @ReneLeyva can you post the code inside your json file ?